# Spatial weight matrix: correspondence between GeoDa and Stata

Tags: geoda, stata

I am trying to Spatial Weight Matrices with Stata and then importing them to GeoDa.

I created an inverse-distance contiguity matrix with Stata, using the process described in the Stata manual, pdf page 110 (link: https://www.stata.com/manuals/sp.pdf). Then, I got help on the Stata forum (source: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1708640-is-there-a-way-to-export-contiguity-weight-matrix-as-gal-file) for the code to transform matrix in .gwt file and import it to GeoDa.

Case 1a: I imported/loaded the matrix successfully to GeoDa; however, GeoDa recognized this matrix as a contiguity row-normalized weight matrix (I realized that due to regression results for SAR model with this matrix in GeoDa and regression results, I ran with normalized row-contiguity matrix in Stata which are the same).

Case 1b: Then, I tried to create an inverse distance weight matrix in GeoDa and, by myself, edit the file deleting units one by one to get the equivalent of this "inverse-distance contiguity matrix" I created with Stata. I imported it to GeoDa again, however, GeoDa treated it again as in Case 1.

Is there any way I could import this .gwt file in GeoDa so that it treats it the same way as Stata?

I think one of the problems is that GeoDa automatically row-normalizes all matrices, and some of those matrices from Stata are spectrally normalized. So, the question can also be, is there a way to turn-off automatic normalization of weight matrices in GeoDa?